# WooCommerce Nodejs Wrapper returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

I am learning to work with the WooCommerce API and I am trying to modify the payment address and the shipping address of a user, but I get this error all the time and I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

The error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

This is my code:

```
var WooCommerceAPI = require("woocommerce-api");

var api = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'https://site.es/',
  consumerKey: 'ck_xxxx',
  consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxx',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v3'
});

const data = {
  first_name: "James",
  billing: {
    first_name: "James",
    postcode: "99502",
 },
  shipping: {
    first_name: "James",
    postcode: "99502",
 }
};

api.putAsync('customers/33', data).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I would really appreciate any help, because really, I don't know what's wrong. I have read a lot about this and I don't see the error.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an outdated version of the library. Use the following one in which all the methods are promisified by default - so, you don't have to perpend "Async" any more.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api-js-lib

```
const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;

const api = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: "http://example.com",
  consumerKey: "ck_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  consumerSecret: "cs_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  version: "wc/v3"
}); 


api.put("customers/33", data)
  .then((response) => {
     ...
```